# Screencast recording performance (using ffmpeg)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, graphics, screen-capture, screencasts

Hello everybody out there doing desktop recordings,

On my old notebook with an Intel Mobile processor with 1.5 GHz and 1 GB RAM, producing a screencast is a pain.

I am using a framerate of 15 fps and a value of 2000M for the rtbufsize option.

There is a nice [help page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20grab%20the%20desktop%20%28screen%29%20with%20FFmpeg) by the ffmpeg developers recommending to do encoding after recording, but this does not seem to make a lot of difference in my case (avi encoder).

[This page](http://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-camtasia-recording-performance-prior.html) by the company developing the commonly used screencast software Camtasia is indicating that CPU performance might be the most critical bottleneck for recording performance.

I would like to know which hardware would be best to use, but the statements from the two different websites seem contradictory to me: If I switch off encoding in ffmpeg, CPU performance should no longer be the bottleneck for screen capture.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What are you recording with? What is your recorded video format? Is this a ffmpeg question at all? What is your OS? If on gnome have you tried the gnome screen recorder? If on windows have you tried camstudio? I refer only to free options here- but of course if you used camtasia you would not have these questions most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Screencast'O'Matic ? (http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/)
It's JAVA Based client to make efficient screencast.